# how to change scheduler header text?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

iam  using devexpress scheduler. in my form iam using

```
   schedulerControl1.ActiveViewType = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerViewType.WorkWeek;            
   schedulerControl1.WorkWeekView.WorkTime.Start = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(7);
   schedulerControl1.WorkWeekView.WorkTime.End = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(22);
   schedulerControl1.WorkWeekView.ShowWorkTimeOnly = true;
   schedulerControl1.WorkWeekView.ShowAllDayArea = false;
```

[image: image 1]

as you can see iam using workweek view, the start week setting properties was monday, but the header is displaying `10 october, 11 october`and so on. the thing is how do i change the scheduler header to day name like `monday, tuesday` and so on.

n.b : if its duplicate please refer it

Answer (score 1):

you can use formatting services (see [Formatting Services - an example of use](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E507.aspx)) for this purpose.

See Also:
[Work Week View without specific dates](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q387797.aspx)

Refer these for the alternative way to implement this:
[How to: Display Custom Day Headers](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4819)
[SchedulerControl.CustomDrawDayOfWeekHeader Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerControl_CustomDrawDayOfWeekHeadertopic)
[How to: Custom Paint Day Headers](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2296)
[CustomDrawDayHeader, how to use custom captions with default background ?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q207823)

Hope this help.